# Mutual information for uncommon words

Tags: text-mining, information-theory

When calculating MI between two words using a big document of about 3000 words, when I calculate the probability of the first word which is not repeated very much in the document, it is very low and the same for the second word; this low value affects the joint probability = `p(x) * P(y)` leading leads to a value of zero or NaN for the mutual information. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I think you have a conceptual problem. If your joint is the product of marginals, mutual information is 0 by definition.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is probably to use negative log probabilities- that will help you avoid underflow. Remember, `p(x) * p(y)` is the same as `-log(p(x)) + -log(p(y))`. For more information, [consult your friendly neighborhood Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability).